# Tried making a custom ScrollView, but instead of scrolling it's spamming up and down

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, uipangesturerecognizer

I tried to create some kind of timeline (with the Vector Illustrator mentality), using UIBezier and UI Label (kind of like in the calendar app) and then use UIPanGestureRecognizer to scroll it up and down. But whenever I scroll it in the simulator, it multiplies itself instead of moving like the images below (I use setNeedsDisplay as the scrollValue changes to redraw the whole mechanism). This is probably a small mistake a I did or maybe my code doesn't work.

I know I could use a UIScrollView or UITableView instead, but I tried making this as a small challenge as a custom made table because using pre-made objects feels limiting for someone like me who is used to CAD drawing or Vector Illustrator.

This image explains what happens in the Simulator:

[image: Image - Project Results]

The code I used is below:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    var tlobject = TimelineView()
    let gesto = UIPanGestureRecognizer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // ===== Add TimelineView Object to view
        let TLObjectFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 40, width: 100, height: 100)
        tlobject = TimelineView(frame: TLObjectFrame)
        view.addSubview(tlobject)
        
        // ===== ADD TOUCH GESTURE =====
        gesto.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touchinput))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(gesto)
    }
    
    var touchStartLocation: Int = 0
    var scrollDistance: Int = 0
    var lastScrollDistance: Int = 0
    
    //The following func calculates the distance scrolled/travelled by Touch gesture on the YAxis and sends the result value (scrollDistance) to the Timeline mechanism where it defines the Yposition of every UIBezier. Thanks to Mitchell Hudson on Youtube for helping me figure out how to do it on his Tutorial "06 11 touches value"
    @objc func touchinput (sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        
        if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began {
            touchStartLocation = Int(sender.location(in: view).y)
            lastScrollDistance = scrollDistance
        }
        
        if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.changed {
            let touchEndLocation = Int(sender.location(in: view).y)
            let currentScrollDistance = touchEndLocation - touchStartLocation
            print("deltaY", currentScrollDistance)
            var newScrollDistance = lastScrollDistance + currentScrollDistance
            scrollDistance = newScrollDistance
            
            tlobject.totalScrollDistance = scrollDistance //send scrollValue to TimelineView
        }
        
        if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.ended {
            print("lastScrollDistance", lastScrollDistance)
            print("scroll Distance", scrollDistance)
        }
    }
}


//Created a new View with the TimeLine mechanism
class TimelineView: UIView {
    
    var totalScrollDistance: Int = 0 {
        didSet{
            setNeedsDisplay() //this gets called everytime UIgesture position changes
        }
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        timelinemechanism()
    }
    
    func timelinemechanism() {
        
        let lineElements: Array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        let spacing: Int = 30
        let scrollDistance: Int = totalScrollDistance
        let totalElements: Int = lineElements.count
        
        for n in 1...totalElements {
            
            //Get UILabel/UILine Yposition on screen = Array index number * the spacing + scroll distance by touch pan gesture
            let yPosition = lineElements[n - 1] * spacing + scrollDistance
            
            let linepath = UIBezierPath()
            linepath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 60, y: yPosition))
            linepath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 300, y: yPosition))
            
            let lineshape = CAShapeLayer()
            lineshape.path = linepath.cgPath
            lineshape.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
            //lineshape.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
            //lineshape.lineWidth = 1
            self.layer.addSublayer(lineshape)
            
            let hourlabel = UILabel()
            hourlabel.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: yPosition - 20, width: 45, height: 40)
            hourlabel.text = "\(n):00"
            //hourlabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Claro", size: 12)
            hourlabel.textColor = UIColor.blue
            hourlabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.right
            self.addSubview(hourlabel)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside `draw` you only have to draw something. You add new subviews/sublayers and do not remove old ones.

Creating a new view every time you change a frame is very resource-intensive. And you don't need that, because you have the same views, you only need to change the position.

Instead, you can create your views at start and use `layoutSubviews` to update your views positions:

```
class TimelineView: UIView {

    var totalScrollDistance: Int = 0 {
        didSet{
            setNeedsLayout() //this gets called everytime UIgesture position changes
        }
    }

    private var lastLayoutTotalScrollDistance: Int = 0

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        createTimelinemechanism()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    var lineShapes = [CAShapeLayer]()
    var hourLabels = [UILabel]()

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let offset = totalScrollDistance - lastLayoutTotalScrollDistance
        lastLayoutTotalScrollDistance = totalScrollDistance
        lineShapes.forEach { lineShape in
            lineShape.frame.origin.y += CGFloat(offset)
        }
        hourLabels.forEach { hourLabel in
            hourLabel.frame.origin.y += CGFloat(offset)
        }
    }

    func createTimelinemechanism() {
        let lineElements: Array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        let spacing: Int = 30
        let totalElements: Int = lineElements.count

        for n in 1...totalElements {

            //Get UILabel/UILine Yposition on screen = Array index number * the spacing + scroll distance by touch pan gesture
            let yPosition = lineElements[n - 1] * spacing

            let linepath = UIBezierPath()
            linepath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 60, y: yPosition))
            linepath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 300, y: yPosition))

            let lineshape = CAShapeLayer()
            lineshape.path = linepath.cgPath
            lineshape.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
            //lineshape.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
            //lineshape.lineWidth = 1

            // disable default layer position animation
            lineshape.actions = [
                "position": NSNull(),
            ]
            self.layer.addSublayer(lineshape)
            lineShapes.append(lineshape)
            let hourlabel = UILabel()
            hourlabel.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: yPosition - 20, width: 45, height: 40)
            hourlabel.text = "\(n):00"
            //hourlabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Claro", size: 12)
            hourlabel.textColor = UIColor.blue
            hourlabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.right
            self.addSubview(hourlabel)
            hourLabels.append(hourlabel)
        }
    }
}
```

More generally, you can just list all the subviews/sublayers and not keep them in separate containers.

Comment: Thanks Philip for your help, it works now :D

Comment: @KikoPerdido You're welcome. If this solved your question, please accept it =) checkmark is under the votes counter

Answer (score 0):

I spent a bit more time with your question since my first thought was wrong. Let me start by saying that your approach here is not the right way to go about this. But it looks to me like you're playing with different aspects of the framework just to learn your way around and I can respect that. I spent many years working on as vector drawing program (Macromedia FreeHand) and even wrote a book about drawing with Quartz 2D back in 2006 so I understand the desire to draw it yourself.

I've reworked your example using "raw" drawing at the CGContext level.  I was playing with your code in a Playground so I restructured the view creation a bit too (just so it shows up in the Playground nicely).  You should be able to copy and paste this into an iOS playground and see the results.

```
//: A UIKit based Playground for presenting user interface
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let gesto = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
    let timelineView = TimelineView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.view.bounds = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 320, height: 700)

        // ===== Add TimelineView Object to view
        view.addSubview(timelineView)
        timelineView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 280, height: 660)
        timelineView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        debugPrint(timelineView.bounds)

        // ===== ADD TOUCH GESTURE =====
        gesto.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touchinput))
        timelineView.addGestureRecognizer(gesto)
    }

    var touchStartLocation: Int = 0
    var scrollDistance: Int = 0
    var lastScrollDistance: Int = 0

    //The following func calculates the distance scrolled/travelled by Touch gesture on the YAxis and sends the result value (scrollDistance) to the Timeline mechanism where it defines the Yposition of every UIBezier. Thanks to Mitchell Hudson on Youtube for helping me figure out how to do it on his Tutorial "06 11 touches value"
    @objc func touchinput (sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began {
            touchStartLocation = Int(sender.location(in: view).y)
            lastScrollDistance = scrollDistance
        }

        if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.changed {
            let touchEndLocation = Int(sender.location(in: view).y)
            let currentScrollDistance = touchEndLocation - touchStartLocation
            print("deltaY", currentScrollDistance)
            scrollDistance = lastScrollDistance + currentScrollDistance

            timelineView.totalScrollDistance = scrollDistance //send scrollValue to TimelineView
        }

        if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.ended {
            print("lastScrollDistance", lastScrollDistance)
            print("scroll Distance", scrollDistance)
        }
    }
}


//Created a new View with the TimeLine mechanism
class TimelineView: UIView {
    var totalScrollDistance: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay() //this gets called everytime UIgesture position changes
        }
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        if let cgContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            drawTimeline(cgContext: cgContext)
        }
    }

    func drawTimeline(cgContext: CGContext) {
        let numElements = 10
        let spacing = 30
        let scrollDistance = totalScrollDistance

        for n in 0..<numElements {
            let yPosition = n * spacing + scrollDistance

            cgContext.saveGState()
            cgContext.setLineWidth(1.0)
            cgContext.setStrokeColor(UIColor.blue.cgColor)

            cgContext.move(to: CGPoint(x: 60, y: yPosition))
            cgContext.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 300, y: yPosition))
            cgContext.strokePath()

            let label : NSString = "\(n):00" as NSString
            label.draw(at: CGPoint(x: 5, y: yPosition - 20),
                       withAttributes: [.foregroundColor : UIColor.blue])
            cgContext.restoreGState()
        }
    }
}

// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

The drawRect of the custom view grabs the current CGContext and passes it to the routine that does the drawing.  Using something like UIBezierPath will work, of course (you saw that it did) but it has overhead (creating an actual object, copying the object into the context graphics state on each drawing, etc) that you don't necessarily need.

I'm not sure what you were doing with CAShapeLayer.  You'd typically use that if you had a shape that you want to animate around the screen.  I suppose you felt that, in scrolling, you might want to do that.  But again this is something where you'd want to create the shape layer outside of the drawing path, keep ahold of it, manipulate it outside of the drawing path, then let the system handle worry about putting it on the screen appriopriately.

Your instincts on text are pretty good.  You really don't want to handle Text drawing yourself in a system as complex as iOS.  There's Unicode issues, glyph substitution, positional forms, ligatures, bi-di text... a whole host of challenges for drawing text on iOS that it's best to leave to things like UILabel.  But you want to keep building your view hierarchy separate from drawing in your view hierarchy.  `drawRect` can be called any time even a pixel of your view needs to be redrawn and adding a new subview each time is not the best way to go.  In my reworked example, I'm drawing the text using NSString - It's still not the "right" way to do it but it's fairly low level while still giving the framework a chance to do some of the text handling.

In the end you would want to work with the frameworks instead of against them.  You'd want to use something like UIScrollView because it will handle a thousand details (bouncing at the boundaries, ease-in/ease-out animation, touch point tracking, fast and slow scrolling, etc) but for a learning experience your code is just fine and I hope you enjoy working with iOS more!

Comment: I should note that my drawing doesn't match yours exactly... the text is out-of-place.   but it should be fairly easy to fix.

Comment: To handle the right justification, with low-level drawing calls, you'd probably use Core Text instead of NSString.

Comment: Thanks for your help Scott, and the time and effort you put into it :), I will go have a look at it when I get to Xcode again. But thanks for the solution and effort :D